# Combine rows in datatable based on data in certain cell

Tags: c#, datatable

I googled a lot and did not find a solution for this. I want to merge rows based on the 'Evalvator' column. I want to merge rows in a way that if Evalvator is '107' i get 'OpravljenihMB' and 'opravljenihLJ' in same row, if data is missing in column then it ads a free space in that cell. Input table looks like this:
[image]

And the output should be like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table [SomeDataTable](
    [Evalvator] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MB] [int] NULL,
    [LJ] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into SomeDataTable
(Evalvator, MB, LJ)
values
(107,10,null),
(109,39,null),
(133,22,null),
(136,50,null),
(137,45,null),
(107,null,57),
(109,null,9),
(136,null,16)

select  distinct dat.Evalvator, MBval.MB, LJval.LJ
from    SomeDataTable dat
left join
(
    select  Evalvator, MB
    from    SomeDataTable
    where   MB is not null
) MBval
on MBval.Evalvator = dat.Evalvator
left join
(
    select  Evalvator, LJ
    from    SomeDataTable
    where   LJ is not null
) LJval
on LJval.Evalvator = dat.Evalvator
```

Maybe this provides some inspiration if you would do it in SQL? Please note the table in this example has no PK, but I assume the data shown in your example is just a snippet of a table with more columns.